# How to configure SSL in camel-rabbitmq?

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, apache-camel

There are only two options in the [`camel-rabbitmq` documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/rabbitmq-component.html). I tried them, but they are not working. So can someone give a small example for configuring the SSL on `camel-rabbitmq`?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Did you try using `sslProtocol=true` as the documentation describes? Did you get any errors? How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: I have put the sslProtocol=true. But it didn't work. I have been also working on it In the web console I saw that ssl port (5671) is not listening at all. Can u tell me how can I do that? Are there any configurations to be done? Thank you in advance